# How long does a PHP MySQL database connection remain active?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have a long running PHP script. I am making the database connection at the very beginning of the script and does some database operation at the start up.

After that, the script perform 4 hours of PHP operation without pinging to MySQL with that connection even a single time.

At the end of these long running PHP operations, when I try to execute `mysql_query` it gives me the following error: `MySQL Server has gone Away`

Is there any possibility of increasing the connection timeout to be 4 hours? I am using `PHP ADODB` to connect with MySQL from my PHP application.

Please suggest what to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MySQL has a different timeout than PHP. You could increase it in `php.ini` on the line `mysql.connect_timeout = 14400`. Also increase the `default_socket_timeout = 14400`

Note that if your PHP setting allow you to do an `ini_set`, you can also do as follows:

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 14400);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 14400);
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works with godaddy shared hosting, thanks