# Update not working while updating

Tags: php

While updating database column about 22000 rows at a time only 6000 data are updating. It doesn't shows any errors!

### here's my code

```
for($i=0;$i<=$total/500;$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<=500;$j++)
    {

        $patient_id[$i][$j] = $rows[$i * 500 +$j]['patient_id'];
        $total_appointment[$i][$j] = $rows[$i*500+$j]
        ['total_appointments'];


        $this->db->set('no_of_appointment',$total_appointment[$i][$j]); 
        $this->db->where('patient_id',$patient_id[$i][$j]);

        $this->db->update('tbl_patients'); 


    }

}
```

Comment: Because you din't applied any error checking code. I think execution time exceeds error will be there after   executing 6000 time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set session timeout in and increase query execution time above your loop

```
set_time_limit( 0 );
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout','7200');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
```

Maybe it solve your error..

Comment: if you change it in php.ini then it required restarting your apache server. and above code also working in a .php file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to increase `mysql.connect_timeout`. Please check the following link for better grasp over it. 
You can increase `mysql.connect_timeout` like the following.
`mysql.connect_timeout = 14400`. Also increase `default_socket_timeout = 14400`.

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 14400);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 14400);
```

For reference, you can check the following link:
[How long does a PHP MySQL database connection remain active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426173)